# Multiple Disqus threads in one view (Localhost) - MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, localhost, bootstrap-modal, disqus

So apparently multiple disqus forums can be loaded using:

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
});
```

(https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites)

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in an MVC view? My application isn't hosted so I'm not sure how to change the url property.

Currently, I have a view with a bunch of images. On image click, a bootstrap modal appears with an enlarged image. I want to load a different disqus thread in each modal.

Is this possible?